# How to config rabbitmq3.7.11 which runs on erlang OTP 21.3 to use ssl to connect python 2.7.5 app client

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, erlang, openstack

I use rabbitmq in openstack which runs on python 2.7.5.The erlang OTP 21.3 rpm comes from rabbitmq team.when i use ssl to connect rabbitmq,i got a error message

" **TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:200 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security - no_suitable_ciphers** "

in rabbitmq log file and a error message

"**SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INSUFFICIENT_SECURITY] tlsv1 alert insufficient security (_ssl.c:579)**"

in openstack service log.

when i switch to erlang OTP 20.3,the error message disappear.so I guess the python 2.7.5 don't support new ciphers,but erlang OTP 21 discards old ciphers and just supports new cipherS.

because of some reasons,i have to use erlang OTP 21.Anyone can tell me how to config rabbitmq or oslo_message to avoid that.Thank you very much.